# Way to open Applications without using Dash (w/out knowing name)?

Tags: unity-dash

In Gnome2 there was a listing of applications installed. Since Gnome3 and Unity, you have to search for the application you want. You can use Run Command but you have to know the name of the app you want to open.

Are there any other ways to open applications besides Dash-Applications-Lens and Run Command?

Comment: For Gnome you could use [GNOME shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) - search for `menu`. Also, if it is compatible, look at the [Axe Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/327/axe-menu/), as that provides a brilliant interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of emulator for the old gnome 2 menu:
You need  to add this ppa:
https://launchpad.net/~diesch/+archive/testing

Execute in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

And then start the program with:

```
classicmenu-indicator
```

Good luck!